# Mass Noun em-dash List-of-Plurals em-dash Verb

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, parentheticals, readability

Is it just me, or?

> All of the content you see on Stack Exchange—all the questions, answers, edits, reviews, users, badges, tags, and more—is stored in a relational database.

Seems technically perfect to me. Why does it not read well, then? The singular *is* after the parenthetical jars, why?

Comment: I don't find it jarring.

Comment: The verb phrase "is stored" agrees with the subject "all".

Comment: @JohnFeltz Of course, it does, else why would it be  "technically perfect"?

Comment: @Kris because the parenthetical is really long and includes 6 plural words and a "more" - there's part of your brain that's numbed by repetition?

Comment: @JohnFeltz You are getting there .... New **tag** to help explain the question.

Comment: You long for a plural verb but the singular is correct. Parentheticals  never govern the verb....

Comment: @Lambie But as John Feltz points out, when the parenthetical is long and contains plurals, your brain easily loses track of the original subject and wants to agree with the more recent nouns.

Comment: What kind of objective answer are you looking for here? Even if something is grammatical, which this is, if it's awkward, it should be rewritten. I could suggest alternative phrasing—but so could any number of other people . . .